# Magento not installing on Localhost

Tags: magento, localhost, installation

trying to install magento 1.7.0.2 on localhost but getting the error "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset."

I'm using wampserver2.2 with Apache 2.2.21, php 5.3.9, MySQL 5.5.20

also enable php extensions php_curl, php_mcrypt

but problem remains same.

Comment: Magento doesn't like to be run on http://localhost/. Add `127.0.0.1 dev.localhost.com` as a new line at the end of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and try loading from `dev.localhost.com` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: does it necessary to touch windows files, need optional path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are installing using install wizard (see http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/installation).

Make sure the checkbox for 'Skip Base URL Validation' is checked.

Also try to avoid using 'localhost', it best to use 'dev.[mysite.com]' because some paid extension will allow you to evaluate their extension without needing a key once your domain start with 'dev.'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I try to install magento on XAMPP 1.7.3 and succesfull..

Follow the steps below :

1) Xampp 1.7.3

2) windowsXP.

a) Create database.

b) Delete app/etc/local.xml file. (Optional not exist leave it)

c) In place of localhost I use 127.0.0.1

d) Go to app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

// session cookie params

$cookieParams = array(

‘lifetime’ => $cookie->getLifetime(),

‘path’ => $cookie->getPath() //, remove the coma

// ‘domain’ => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),

// ‘secure’ => $cookie->isSecure(),

// ‘httponly’ => $cookie->getHttponly()

);

e) I add one line in index.php at start of file 
set_time_limit (18000);

f) In Web access options -> Checklist Enable Chart and Skip Base URL

now installation work good for me.. :D

**For attention** : you must modified your XAMPP

go to -> httpd.conf

Look for this line :

## LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Remove "#" to enable it and save

and on

php.ini - find this line

;extension=php_curl.dll

Remove ";" to enable it and save.